# Does installing the same Windows 7 copy on 2 computers deactivate the previous installation?

Tags: windows-7, license, windows-activation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When reinstalling Windows 7, does the language, version, architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) or source (OEM, retail, or MSDN) matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-reinstalling-windows-7-does-the-language-version-architecture-64-bit-or)

Does installing the same Windows 7 copy on 2 computers deactivate the previous installation?

For example, if I install a legitimate copy of Windows 7 onto my PC and activate it, then use the same disk and key on another PC and activate it, will it deactivate my previous installation? Or will it not let me activate the 2nd one until I deactivate the previous one?

Answer (score 3):

It will not let you activate it on the 2nd one. And I'm not sure there's a possibility to "deactivate" an installation.

There's always the possibility to call Microsoft support and tell them you've installed your windows 7 on a new PC, and then they can de-activate the previous one for you (I think it's like that). Then you can re-activate it on your new PC (but it won't stay activated on your previous one).

Comment: This is not true. If you are going to activate a second PC with the same product key as the first one, the first PC will not loose its activation.

Answer (score 1):

Beta and RC installations of W7 allow a few (3?) activations on one licence. RTM and later will almost certainly be one activation per key

Comment: RC allows for at closer to 10 .. I've got heaps of PC's running RC, but no activation errors.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 RTM has been released on MSDN for the subscribers. There are keys also available. Each MSDN key should allow about 10 activations. I've activated Windows 7 on two virtual machines with the same MSDN key.

Answer (score 0):

With a normal key, it should not let you activate on the second machine (sometimes it will if it thinks the hardware is similar - I have seen this - but would not recommend trying it because that would be very naughty).

It will not deactivate the first machine in any case.

MSDN/TechNet... they do usually come in packs.  The number depends on the level of your subscription, so yes you can reuse the key up to however many you have been assigned.