# How to find Windows 8 OEM product key?

Tags: windows, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find the product key that was used to activate Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/495794/how-can-i-find-the-product-key-that-was-used-to-activate-windows-8)

Comment: There should be a sticker on the laptop somewhere (usually on the bottom) which will have your product key on it.

Comment: @Brutick yeah, usually there is one, but I looked and there isn't on my laptop =(

Comment: I also found this question which may be relevant to your issue: http://superuser.com/questions/312610/recovering-oem-license-information-from-hp-notebook-serial-number?rq=1

Comment: Just uninstall the stuff you don't want.

Comment: If you don't see a COA attached to the laptop somewhere, [it may not be genuine Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/howtotell/Hardware.aspx#PCPurchase). Try looking in the battery compartment. Sometimes they put it there.

Comment: @user22105 I got your deletion request, but decided not to delete it at this time because your question actually has more views than the targeted duplicate. I guess something about your wording is better for search engines. Eventually (like in a few months) if it hasn't gotten too many more views and the other one is catching up, we can delete it. (For reference: we're at 2500 now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NirSoft ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html):

[image]

NirSoft makes tools that rival SysInternals in their usefulness; except nobody remember's their name (not even me). They're like the *["that guy from terminator"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Biehn)* - but for software.

Comment: Win8 is not mentioned in ProduKey's Supported Products List. Does it actually work with the new OS?

Comment: NirSoft does not seem to be working with Windows 8. It is not returning the right keys.

Comment: i've tried it, on Windows 8; it does return my product key.

Answer (score 4):

For Win8 OEM devices there is no key on a sticker. The key is embedded to the BIOS.

http://www.ghacks.net/2012/11/23/bios-embedded-windows-8-product-keys/

The [Windows 8 Product Key Viewer](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/30363-Windows-8-WDP-Product-Key-Viewer) should work and read the correct produkt key.

// Edit: [R-W Everything](http://rweverything.com/download/) also shows the key under ACPI->MSDM

[image]

Comment: Windows 8 Product Key Viewer worked for me!! :3

Comment: Also, the free OEM Product Key tool from NeoSmart: https://neosmart.net/OemKey/

Answer (score -1):

You can try Magical Jellybean; just tested and although it doesn't mention windows 8 it shows my key.

http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/