# How do I install Windows 10 installation on my Windows 8.1 OEM laptop?

Tags: windows-installation, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, oem

I bought a laptop with windows 8.1 pre-installed, and got an OEM flash drive with windows 8.1 installation. Now I've successfully upgraded to Windows 10. How could I install windows 10 on my laptop even after, other words - how to become Windows 10 owner (not 8.1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download Windows 10 with the media creation tool from Microsoft.
With that tool you can make a bootable USB installation with a Windows 10 installer.

Comment: So from this point, that wouldn't be a problem to install windows 10 on my windows 8.1 OEM laptop? Or I should pay for this option in future?

Comment: No that would not be a problem i did the same with my laptop and it worked

Comment: You can download the tool with this link: [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

Comment: But always make sure u have a copy of your license key!

Comment: That's a problem. I have no key. It's OEM (have been write to the motherboard)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/509773/how-to-find-windows-8-oem-product-key :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I asked this question from DELL, and they told that this impossible to grab key from OEM, that's why they send me a bootable flash :D

Comment: Your welcome! Hahaha yeah i know your problem DELL wants to have closed systems thats why they are saying that kind of answers:/