# Windows: DISM: Error: 0x800f0906: The source files could not be downloaded

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, dism

I tried to run DISM but got this error. I plugged in the Windows 8 USB stick that I requested from Dell (no CD-ROMs were provided) and re-ran it with the `source` options and it *still* gave the error. I read the [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825020.aspx) but it didn't make much sense and didn't say exactly what a source was. I don't know what a group policy is, or what a WIM is. Windows Update already works OK. I searched for 'group policy' on my system and in Control Panel, but nothing was found. I don't know why it can't just download the files it needs.

```
C:\windows\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:j:\

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031

[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x800f0906

The source files could not be downloaded.
Use the "source" option to specify the location of the files that are required t
o restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

`dism.log`

```
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6660 TID=3576  Error in operation: (null) (CBS HRESULT=0x800f0906) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6660 TID=4736 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x800f0906)
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6660 TID=4736 The source files could not be found and download failed. Their location can be specified using the /source option to restore the feature. - GetCbsErrorMsg
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6660 TID=4736 Failed processing package changes with session option CbsSessionOptionRepairStoreCorruption - CDISMPackageManager::RestoreHealth(hr:0x800f0906)
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6660 TID=4736 The source files could not be found and download failed. Their location can be specified using the /source option to restore the feature. - GetCbsErrorMsg
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6660 TID=4736 Failed to restore the image health. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ProcessCmdLine_CleanupImage(hr:0x800f0906)
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6660 TID=4736 Failed while processing command cleanup-image. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f0906)
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6660 TID=4736 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Found the PE Provider.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Package Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=6660 TID=4736 Finalizing CBS core. - CDISMPackageManager::Finalize
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Disconnecting Provider: DISM Package Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Finalizing the servicing provider(MsiManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Disconnecting Provider: MsiManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Finalizing the servicing provider(IntlManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Disconnecting Provider: IntlManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Finalizing the servicing provider(IBSManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Disconnecting Provider: IBSManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Finalizing the servicing provider(DriverManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Disconnecting Provider: DriverManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Finalizing the servicing provider(DISM Unattend Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Disconnecting Provider: DISM Unattend Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Finalizing the servicing provider(SmiManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Disconnecting Provider: SmiManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Finalizing the servicing provider(AppxManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Disconnecting Provider: AppxManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Finalizing the servicing provider(AssocManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Disconnecting Provider: AssocManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Finalizing the servicing provider(GenericManager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Disconnecting Provider: GenericManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Finalizing the servicing provider(Edition Manager) - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Disconnecting Provider: Edition Manager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Releasing the local reference to OSServices. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Disconnecting Provider: OSServices - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6660 TID=4736 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session has been closed. Reboot required=no.
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: <----- Ending Dism.exe session ----->
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: 
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6640 TID=6872 Found the OSServices.  Waiting to finalize it until all other providers are unloaded. - CDISMProviderStore::Final_OnDisconnect
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6640 TID=6872 Disconnecting Provider: FolderManager - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
2017-11-03 18:12:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=6640 TID=6872 Releasing the local reference to DISMLogger.  Stop logging. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_DisconnectProvider
```

[`cbs.log`](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/starrychloe/2f813374e4da14dfe2595255865dbcd5/raw/7c9b2885d1638b44952f2d77325abb6a4ffd554c/cbs.log)

---

Attempt to add MSU files to WIM:

```
C:\windows\system32>md \temp\windows
C:\Users\Chloe\Downloads>dism /mount-image imagefile:"c:\images\install.wim" /index:1 /mountdir:c:\temp\windows

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Error: 3

The system cannot find the path specified.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log

C:\Users\Chloe\Downloads>dism /add-package /image:c:\temp\windows /packagepath:"*.msu" /logpath:addpackage.log

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Error: 2

Unable to access the image.
Make sure that the image path and the Windows directory for the image exist and you have Read permissions on the folder.

The DISM log file can be found at addpackage.log
```

`addpackage.log`

```
...
2017-11-13 18:18:29, Info                  DISM   DISM WIM Provider: PID=9672 TID=7456 [c:\temp\windows] is not a WIM mount point. - CWimMountedImageInfo::Initialize
2017-11-13 18:18:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Imaging Provider: PID=9672 TID=7456 The provider WimManager does not support CreateDismImage on c:\temp\windows - CGenericImagingManager::CreateDismImage
2017-11-13 18:18:29, Info                  DISM   DISM Imaging Provider: PID=9672 TID=7456 No imaging provider supported CreateDismImage for this path - CGenericImagingManager::CreateDismImage
2017-11-13 18:18:29, Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: Failed to access the image folder or image's windows folder.
2017-11-13 18:18:29, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE: Image session has been closed. Reboot required=no.
2017-11-13 18:18:29, Info                  DISM   DISM.EXE:
```

Windows 8.1

Comment: Try the net start and stop processes from admin elevated command prompt listed here on this list as **#2** and then retry the admin elevated dism command prompt afterwards: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-corrupt-windows-image-error-0x800f0906

Comment: looks like a file is corrupted that was updated later via an update so the file is not part of the original WIM. look in the CBS.log which file version you need and add this update to the WIM with DISM first.

Comment: have you looked in the CBS logs to see which file version are missing?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here is [cbs.log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/starrychloe/2f813374e4da14dfe2595255865dbcd5/raw/7c9b2885d1638b44952f2d77325abb6a4ffd554c/cbs.log).

Comment: ok, I posted what I saw from the CBS.log. add the updates to the WIM and use the new WIM as source with DISM

Comment: "I searched for 'group policy' on my system and in Control Panel, but nothing was found." - You are running Windows 8.1, the group policy editor requires Windows 8.1 Professional+, you are running Windows 8.1 (aka Windows 8.1 Core).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by running

```
C:\Windows\System32\wbem>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031

[==========================100.0%==========================]
The operation completed successfully.

C:\Windows\System32\wbem>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031

[==========================100.0%==========================]
The restore operation completed successfully. The component store corruption was
 repaired.
The operation completed successfully.
```

[Source](https://deploymentpros.wordpress.com/tag/dism-cleanup-image/)

[This](https://superuser.com/a/1282934/130929) may also be required, but if I remember correctly, DISM still did not complete correctly right after that.

There is also a [Microsoft guy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/joscon/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012/) actively answering DISM problems in the comments. I didn't need to use him. Post your `CBS.log` and `DISM.log` and console output and he may be able to help if this answer doesn't.

Comment: Jason no longer works in this windows support

Answer (score 0):

Here are the corrupted files:

```
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         amd64_microsoft-windows-ie-memoryanalyzer_31bf3856ad364e35_11.0.9600.18793_none_c692555cd6a574c3\MemoryAnalyzer.dll
Repair failed: Missing replacement payload.
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         amd64_juniper-vpnplugin-appx_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.17093_none_4788d83836273476\resources.pri
Repair failed: Missing replacement payload.
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt (Fixed) amd64_microsoft-windows-ie-memoryanalyzer_31bf3856ad364e35_11.0.9600.18450_none_c6af0850d6906eb1\MemoryAnalyzer.dll
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         amd64_microsoft-windows-ie-ieetwcollector_31bf3856ad364e35_11.0.9600.18321_none_c6d63f4ce5c07126\ieetwcollectorres.dll
Repair failed: Missing replacement payload.
(p) CSI Payload Corrupt         amd64_microsoft-windows-errorreportingcore_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16408_none_118f948ed996c558\werdiagcontroller.dll
Repair failed: Missing replacement payload.
```

`11.0.9600.18793` comes from [KB4036586](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4036586), to see which KB updates VPN to `6.3.9600.17093` open `regedit.exe`, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\ComponentDetect\amd64_juniper-vpnplugin-appx_31bf3856ad364e35_0.0.0.0_none_d6cef60e62aeb6a8` and look which KB updates the file to `6.3.9600.17093` , `11.0.9600.18450` is [KB3185319](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3185319), `11.0.9600.18321` comes from [KB3154070](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3154070) , `6.3.9600.16408` comes from [Windows 8.1 General Availability Update Rollup KB2883200](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB2883200).

Download the MSU files and add them to the `Install.wim` [with DISM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-updates-to-customized-windows-and-winpe-images). Now run `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:D:\install.wim:1 /limitaccess` and use the updated WIM as source which includes now all files.

Comment: OK I tried to add the MSU files to a WIM, but got an error. I updated the question. There is no `C:\images`.

Comment: I tried again by creating an empty WIM file, but it still didn't work: https://gist.github.com/starrychloe/e6d77ada267e726d12c289f1ccae12f3

Comment: don't capture a new WIM. Mount the original install.wim from your Windows 8.1 DVD/ISO into a mount point. this is explained in detail in the MS documentation. you have to create your own folder structure and copy the files there.

Comment: OK I copied the Windows 8.0 install.wim onto my C: drive and added 6 packages and committed the changes, but it still said "The source files could not be found." https://gist.github.com/starrychloe/094cfc0befdac67055c877ad7d4fe575

Comment: you haven't posted the mount. ,make sure you mounted the correct Index and updated the correct one (install.wim:1). so if you mounted index 2 the files can't be found. also 1 hint. you can store all MSUs in 1 folder and use folder only /packagepath:C:\MSU whene trying to add them. now DISM will pick all files.

Comment: I _did_ use `index 1`. https://gist.github.com/starrychloe/86be450291addaf283036b5b8dcc607a

Comment: I even ran it again without an error and it still said 'no found'. https://gist.github.com/starrychloe/96e63d55984d559b7ec4a8c308ca2db4

Comment: make sure your installed Windows SKU is the same like in your WIM at this index.

Comment: I don't know what a SKU is. I have Windows 8.1 installed. It updated itself after it came out. The computer came with 8.0. The USB stick is 8.0. I don't have a WIM on my C: drive in \WINDOWS.

Comment: SKU = edition. So do yo use Core/Home or Pro? Also you can't use a Windows 8(.0) WIM, you need a Windows 8.1 WIM.

Comment: I use Windows Home, not Pro. I don't have an 8.1 WIM. It updated itself to 8.1 through Windows Update.

Comment: get the 8.1 WIM from here: https://tb.rg-adguard.net/index.php?lang=en-US&extract, selct Windows (final) and Windows 8.1

Comment: That didn't work either. I extracted `sources\install.wim` from `Win8.1_English_x64.iso`: https://gist.github.com/starrychloe/a0f0ce4b3dd339a546e4f5167ede39ca

Comment: if you use Core/Home use Index 2, index 1 of the ISO is Win8.1 Pro.

Comment: Index 2 didn't work: https://gist.github.com/starrychloe/206195f208c2c9112a92f837d4b93b38

Comment: you need to share the CBS.log which shows the files that still can't be repaired.

Comment: OK I updated the gist with the CBS.log at the end. https://gist.github.com/starrychloe/206195f208c2c9112a92f837d4b93b38#file-dism-doesn-t-work-with-index-2-L279

Comment: I have no real idea why it till fails. mount the 8.1 ISO in a virtual DVD drive, run [setup.exe and select "Keep Windows settings, personal files, and apps" to do a repair install](https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/26095-repair-install-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: That says it needs a product key, but I don't have a product key since it came pre-installed with my computer from Dell.

Comment: the [key is stored in BIOS/UEFI since Win8 for OEM devices](https://superuser.com/a/509806/174557). I don't know if 8.1 setup accepts the 8.0 key from UEFI

Comment: I intend to never buy a Microsoft operating system again. My next operating system will be Apple MacOS or Linux. This is ridiculous that the OS can become corrupted and there is no way to fix it.

Comment: with Mac you also have a lot of issues and a shorter usage of the device, because support of older Macs is removed after 4-5 years.