# Can MSDNAA copies of software be transferred to new computers?

Tags: license, msdn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 and Vista Activation FAQ: how do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit-a)

My university provided me with a copy of Windows 7 Pro x64 under that MSDN Academic Alliance as well as various other software.

I installed this on an existing Windows Vista Home Premium laptop (clean install) at the beginning of last year. I am now buying a new laptop, which comes with Windows 7 Home Premium x64. Is it possible to transfer my pro license to this new laptop and restore the old laptop to Vista (using the original license key that came with the laptop)? Likewise can I move any of my other MSDNAA software to the new computer?

As I understand it MSDNAA is different from the MSDN subscriptions, but I'm not sure if the same rules apply, and the license docs provided are not the easiest things to read.

Comment: from what i recall from MSDNAA, you could get more than one key, though. I'll be getting access again in two weeks, so i'll know for sure then

Answer (score 0):

The MSDNAA product keys are only good for one activation.  Period.  The purpose of the program is to teach students the Microsoft technology.  After you learn the software, Microsoft wants you or your company to purchase the software.

Comment: If this is true, they've changed the terms since I was a student. But then, that was 10 years ago, so it's entirely possible.