# Installing Microsoft Windows 7 x64 on eeepc 1215n, without violating the law

Tags: windows-7, eee-pc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)
>   [Windows Vista/7 Activation FAQ: How do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-vista-7-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit-and)

I've got an Asus Eee PC 1215n. The CPU is an Intel Atom D525 (a 64-bit processor with two cores in hyper-threading). It is distributed with Windows 7 Home Premium (**32 bit** edition).

I upgraded it installing 4 GB of RAM, and I would like to take the best from it installing a 64 bit OS.

I want to have a 100% clean and legal system, without cracked software on it, including the O.S.

If I can acquire the install media for the 64-bit version, may I upgrade to 64 bit using **the same serial number** on the sticker stuck to the laptop?

I am trying to acquire the media legally, should I contact Asus or Microsoft?

Comment: techie007, thanks for the edit. Still, I would like to know HOW can I acquire that media, legally. Would you mind editing again restoring the original meaning?

Comment: ok I'll read that topic :)

Comment: See the dupe regarding "if you can use the key you have with a different version/media".  To get "legit" media you should contact Microsoft and see what your options are.  Generally if you have a legit key, you can use any valid install media, regardless of how you acquired it.

Comment: I love these questions, because the answer tends to boil down to "open up your wallet."

Comment: @surfasb: yeah, but fortunately not in this case