# Is there a way to upgrade to windows 64 bits with no new installation?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 and Vista Activation FAQ: How do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit)

I have windows 7 ultimate 32 bits, but I need to install some programs by Adobe that requires 64 bits version. Is there any way I can upgrade to 64 bits with no new installation? Because I don't want to upgrade all my files and get through all that long process installing all again. Unfortunately I don't have the time too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the future, perhaps try a search first, as this has been asked a million and one times... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly... No.  The very core of Windows must be replaced with all the components that are designed around 64-bits instead of 32-bits.