# Can I use the same Windows 7 licence key after changing motherboard or processor?

Tags: windows, license, license-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 and Vista Activation FAQ: How do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit)

I am using Windows 7 Professional. Now if I want to change my processor or motherboard, is it possible to use the same licence key on my PC?

Comment: Check out this question http://superuser.com/q/303136/128794

Answer (score 4):

If it is an OEM version of Windows 7, then CPU and motherboard upgrades will violate the EULA. So, you may not be able to activate it. OEM copies of Windows are tied to the motherboard/CPU they are installed on first.

If you are using a retail Windows version then you can move it to a different computer as many times as you like.  Of course, it can only be installed on one computer at a time.

If you do want further clarification you could always call Microsoft and ask them directly.

Comment: I think the OP meant his Windows Key, not his keyboard

Comment: ha, yeah you are probably right.  Talk about reading the question wrong, :).