# Transfer Windows 7 OEM license before booting new laptop

Tags: windows-7, license

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 and Vista Activation FAQ: How do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit)

I don't need Windows and I am buying a new laptop. **New laptop** (Lenovo L530) **includes OEM Windows 7 PRO license** and there is nothing I can do to avoid buying the OS. Since, my family can use Windows on another computer, is it possible to transfer the license there? The **difference between other usual OEM transfer cases** is that **I will never boot new laptop** with the Windows OS (I will format it immediately).

My more specific questions: (1) will the new Windows 7 PRO OS be pre-activated when I will receive my new laptop? (2) Will the new OS be tied to the new laptop in the factory and not during activation / installation process and there is nothing I can do?

I tried researching this, but nothing helps. I only found that one can use manual activation method by phone to convince the operator you have broken your laptop and need an OS license transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what Microsoft generally says in situations like these (see nerdwaller's answer), but I would still suggest you ask Lenovo about it since it's finally up to the manufacturer (Microsoft has already got its money). OEM versions are normally tied to the hardware they're installed on, so while a license transfer might not be possible, **a refund [*might*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_refund#Lenovo)** be (although going by reports it won't be easy). Still, no harm in asking them (ask Support to escalate it and don't be satisfied with some Level 1 guy saying No).

Comment: I actually called Lenovo on this when I bought my laptop two months ago.  I took it up three levels and tried multiple times to try the same thing.  I was unlucky, I hope @Tautrimas has more luck than me!

Comment: As you can see from that Wikipedia article, it's difficult, requires a *lot* of persistence and probably will not succeed in all locations.

Comment: No kidding, that's really funny (and worth not taking for all that).  Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: @nerdwaller, thank you for inspiration. I am aware of the license refund and I will really try to do that in my country (Lithuania).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately Not.

From Microsoft's FAQ:

> [Microsoft Licensing FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/licensing_faq.aspx#fbid=PrG-E_DD_iF?faq3)
>
> Q. Can my customers transfer or sell their OEM software licenses?
>
> A. After an OEM software license has been installed on a PC, the license may not be installed on or transferred to another PC. However, the entire PC may be transferred to another end user along with the software license rights. When transferring the PC to the new end user, the software media, manuals (if applicable), and Certificate of Authenticity label must be included. It is also advisable to include the original purchase invoice or receipt. The original end user cannot keep any copies of the software.
>
> Q. My customer bought a new PC and wants to move the OEM software from the old PC to the new one. Can't users do whatever they want with their software?
>
> A. No, the OEM software is licensed with the computer system on which it was originally installed and is tied to that original machine. OEM licenses are single-use licenses that cannot be installed on more than one computer system, even if the original machine is no longer in use. The End User Software License Terms, which the end user must accept before using the software, state that the license may not be shared, transferred to, or used concurrently on different computers. System builders must provide end-user support for the Windows license on computers they build, but cannot support licenses on computers they didn’t build. This is a fundamental reason why OEM System Builder licenses can't be transferred.