# Is a Windows 7 OEM Key valid for 32bit and 64bit?

Tags: windows, licensing

I have a Sony Vaio VPCEC15FG laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-Bit OS (Genuine).
Are there any legal problems for burning a customized Windows 7 DVD and keeping it in hand?

Since they are not releasing the SP2, I am planning to integrate all security updates to the DVD using some third party tools like RT7Lite and to keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To answer your first question regarding 32-Bit and 64-Bit
  Yes, its allowed and it will work
  Windows 7 Retail DVDs always contain x64 and x86 versions - OEM DVDs doesn't (thx@Phillip R)
- Your second question about legal problems with slipstreaming servicepacks & updates
  Thats also allowed
- Please have also a look at the community wiki: [Windows 7 Activation FAQ](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit)
  It answers your first question very well

<del>PS: I recommend [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/nlite.html) for those tasks</del>
Beside your own recommendation RT7Lite you can try [7Customizer](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/139077-7customizer-a-windows-7-customization-and-deployment-tool/)

Comment: Thak you for your answer, but nLite supports only  Windows 2000, XP x86/x64 and 2003 x86/x64, and I have Windows 7. So RT7 Lite may be used, isn't it? Do you have any other better suggestion?

Comment: @Hari: Oh, my fault, see my edit. Some people reported that they have slipstreamed Windows 7 and SP1 with vLite, the successor of nLite. But vLite doesn't support Windows 7 officially.

Comment: Regarding OEM disks. They will usually only supply you with 32 or 64 media not both, but the key will work with either.