# Windows 7 OEM 64 bit installation

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-installation

I am a new user to SU. Sorry if this has already been asked before. I did ask a user in a comment a while back.

Anyway here goes :
I assembled my own PC. I purchased the OEM version from the market here in India of Windows 7 Home Basic 32 bit.

I have since upgraded my RAM to 8 GB the maximum permissible under Windows 7 Home Basic.

I am trying to upgrade my OS to 64 bit. For that I downloaded Windows 7 from Microsoft. I could only get Professional edition. OK No problem. I downloaded the ei cfg utility that removes the ei cfg file from the ISO. But while installing it did not present me with a choice of OS versions. It only installed the professional version.

So I restored the ei cfg file, changed the version to Windows 7 Home Basic. Now while booting from DVD-ROM I get an error saying the key does not match any of the images.

I am legitimate user, but these days it is difficult to find the links to my version on DigitalRiver.

What am I doing wrong? I realize the setup has changed.

Is there a pre-SP1 version that gives me OS choices? (I would appreciate links official or torrents).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. But check out: [Windows 7 and Vista Activation FAQ: How do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](http://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit) and [Where do I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you right now why the key doesn't work. You purchased a 32-bit version with a 32-bit key. It's not happy your using a 64-bit version with a 32-bit key. The only thing I can think of if you want to stay a legitimate user is to call Microsoft and ask if you can trade your 32-bit key for a 64-bit key. The may or may not allow you to do this. Sorry.

Comment: "You are free to switch between a 64-bit and 32-bit version of Windows at any time. This requires a reinstall, but you can use the same license key. Depending on how recently you have reinstalled, reactivation may be possible over the internet, or may require you to call the activation hotline." [SU link](http://superuser.com/a/303137/23133)

Comment: Not true if you buy a 32-bit exclusive.

Comment: notice the fact that he said OEM'

Comment: The reactivation hotline will most likely just make the key active on 64-bit. But you still have to call

Comment: If that's the case, then I suggest you suggest an edit to that linked answer. :)  But yeah, it may depend on the OEM itself as well (i.e. HP has different rules than Dell), and yeah calling MS for guidance is a good suggestion. PS: I didn't down-vote you. :)

Comment: Oh good. If you got it through a company have fun. They make you contact the company then the company makes you contact them and it's the biggest hell you will ever experience.

Comment: @techie007 It's already there look a the licence type it says "transferable between computers" which if he has an OEM from a company that has been activated on another computer an he is trying to put it on his own of course it's not going to.

Comment: I beleive he says he's trying to side-grade his existing computer to 64-bit.  No transference of license.

Comment: If that is the case he may still need to call and have them reactivate with 64 bit

Comment: +1 OEM versions can indeed be 32 or 64-bit only, and I agree that calling the activation hotline might be the best possible solution to sort this out. But perhaps before that he can try the key with the generic retail 64-bit Home Basic version of Win7.

Comment: @Karan Thank you. techie had me worried I was wrong

Comment: FWIW, unlike the other answer I have had no problems whatsoever activating OEM keys using retail DVDs. I do this fairly often since I reinstall Windows on every new machine to get rid of the manufacturer's crapware, and barring one instance I have never had activation fail me while using OEM/COA SLP keys with the retail Win7 DVD. (OEM keys for XP weren't so tolerant OTOH.)

Comment: I think in this case it may be because it's Home Basic. Windows 7 Home Basic has some geographic licensing restrictions, and it's possible that's causing you the problems.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer, since I ended up contacting MS support anyway. Just waiting for them to reply.