# Microsoft Windows license - using Windows Upgrade License for downgrade

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, license, downgrade

At the moment I'm using an old laptop that previously had Windows Vista OEM. I upgraded it to Win7HP using Upgrade Box bought at local retailer.

Now I want to buy myself a new laptop, but the one I chose has Win8 preinstalled. Since I'm going to format the old computer and install linux on it, will I be able to use the Win7 upgrade box license on the new computer as a downgrade option? I don't really like the new Windows and would like to use Win7...

Comment: Because you are dealing with OEM licenses they cannot be transfered between computers. If you want to use Windows 7 that will require a new license. Even if you try the installation will not activate on the new computer.  Here is one of many questions on the subject http://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to chat with Microsoft Support. It appears, that I need to install older Windows (Win Vista OEM from old computer should be enough according to the support) and then use the Windows 7 Update Box to upgrade the OS to Win7.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the upgrade license will only work for previous versions of windows and not later versions.

I agree that Windows 7 is far superior to 8 but I am not going to open that can of worms here. If you have a vista disk, install that first then upgrade.

Comment: why would someone vote this negatively when ITS WHAT I SAID!