# Have a legitimate Windows 7 license and the Windows 7 key but don't have the DVD

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-activation

I just booted up my 'old' PC that's been lying around for the last two years. I have Windows 7 on it and I'm looking to format the drive and do a fresh install of W7.

I have the key for Windows 7 in a text file. However I don't have the Windows 7 DVD or image.

1. So is there any way of burning off a Windows 7 DVD considering that its the operating system I'm currently using?
2. If not...well I have a W7 key, will this key work with any W7 DVD or is it particular to the W7 image that came with the key?

Comment: You might be able to download the ISO from [Microsoft Subscriber Downloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/downloads/) (but you will of course need the product key to make much use of it). Have you tried that?

Comment: Your key will work fine with an image you can download from MS, as long as you download and install the right version.  There are many different ["flavors"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions) of Windows 7, so make sure you get the right one.

Comment: Related questions: [Where can I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft), [Windows 7 and Vista Activation FAQ: How do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](http://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the ISO file from the links mentioned in this SU question here: [Where can I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)

The key is not specific to the DVD. You can burn a DVD using the ISO and this software: http://www.freeisoburner.com/