# Installing Windows 8 on a second hard drive

Tags: windows-8, license

I purchased a copy of Windows 8 Pro back when it first came out (when it was the upgrade offer for £25). I'm now in the market for a hard drive upgrade (HDD to SSD) but I'm not sure about my options when it comes to the Windows 8 license.

Ideally I'd like to install Windows 8 from scratch so I can start with a clean slate, however I realise this will mean I'll need to enter my product key again which might cause problems. Otherwise I've seen articles which talk about backing up Windows 8 and then restoring on the new HD but I guess this wouldn't give me the fresh start I'm after.

Apart from some additional RAM the rest of the hardware is staying the same, somewhere I've got it in my head that because the motherboard will be the same then it might let me off.

Has anyone done similar and what was the outcome?

Comment: It should Just Work. In the worst case you'll have to activate over the phone.

Comment: So my license is valid for multiple installations? I figured that if/when it phoned home it would be flagged as already in use.

Comment: It is tied to one PC, but you can install it multiple times and small hardware changes are allowed. It *may* detect those hardware changes and that's why you may have to activate it via phone, but it's allowed and legal. Here's a [related question for Windows Vista/7](http://superuser.com/q/303136/194694), but it's still valid for Windows 8. You can try to transfer your activation as described there.

Comment: You can even change your pc and reactivate your non-oem license. Obviously the first pc will be deactivated at 1st connection..

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a clean installation of Windows 8 Pro to a new hard drive and re-use your existing license that was included with your computer as long as:

1. You delete the instance of Windows on your original hard drive, and
2. You continue using the **same motherboard** on which the license was first used

According to the [Microsoft OEM Partner Center's Licensing FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/Pages/licensing_faq.aspx#fbid=KFBmI2KOJWl):

> Generally, an end user can upgrade or replace all of the hardware components on a computer—**except the motherboard**—and still retain the license for the original Microsoft OEM operating system software. If the motherboard is upgraded or replaced for reasons other than a defect, then a new computer has been created. Microsoft OEM operating system software cannot be transferred to the new computer, and the license of new operating system software is required. If the motherboard is replaced because it is defective, you do not need to acquire a new operating system license for the PC as long as the replacement motherboard is the same make/model or the same manufacturer's replacement/equivalent, as defined by the manufacturer's warranty.

The FAQ goes on to state that Microsoft considers the motherboard *"the 'heart and soul' of the PC"* and that only *"when the motherboard is replaced (for reasons other than defect) a new PC is essentially created"*.

Therefore, you are free to install Windows from scratch to your new hard drive.  Typically when only one key hardware component (your HDD) is changed [Windows Product Activation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/wpa_overview.mspx?mfr=true) will succeed without issue.  However, if it were to fail for some reason, simply call Microsoft at the number provided in the Activation Wizard and explain that you are reinstalling Windows to a new hard drive in an already licensed computer.