# Windows 7 "no longer genuine" after cloning failing hard drive to new hard drive with Norton Ghost

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation, norton-ghost

I have a laptop. Every time it booted, Windows 7 popped up an error message stating that the hard drive had reported a fault and that it should be backed up.

I cloned the drive using Norton Ghost to a new hard drive (I couldn't use Windows Back Up to do it because the new drive is a smaller SSD and it wouldn't allow me to restore the image) but now Windows claims that it's not genuine. I've definitely typed in the correct product code from the label on the bottom of the laptop.

I tried following the Windows 7 steps shown here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950929 but activating online fails and redirects me to a page to buy a new copy of Windows and I don't get given the option to activate by phone as shown in their screen shot.

I still have the old hard drive (so long as it doesn't fail) if that helps.

Comment: If there is a number to call, I can't find it. I'm in the UK.

Comment: It's because the HDD serial number is one of the things Windows monitors to detect piracy.  You need to contact MS by phone and get them to help you re-activate it.  Are you not getting the dialog window with the option to phone them a tall, or is the link just missing from the windows?  Is your Windows an OEM copy (came with the notebook)?

Comment: Try [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/33495-uk-activation-phone-number-needed.html#post341517) maybe: In the 'Run' command box -> `slui 4`. The toll-free number is `0800-018-8354`

Comment: This is the window I get when I run slui 4. http://news.techgenie.com/files/This-Copy-of-Windows-Is-Not-Genuine.jpg - Note no option for phone activation. Windows came with the computer. It has the product key on a sticker on the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the copy of Windows you have has been, and still is, activated.  So, when you try to activte it, this will fail since it has already been done.

Now, you have what MS calls a "Major Hardware Change", and you need to do 2 things:

1. Deactivate your current Windows while booted to the SSD.
2. Then, re-activate, try online, but if that fails, then you should be given a phone number to call in, and it is usually an automated process where you type in numbers and get a response.

Here is how you de-activate windows:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/165472-product-key-number-uninstall-deactivate-windows.html

1. Open an elevated command prompt.
2. In the elevated command prompt, copy and paste the command below and press enter:

slmgr.vbs /upk

3. Reboot and activate using the product key on the bottom, make sure you are online if you want to activate over the internet.

If the online fails, you should be given a phone number now.  If for some odd reason you don't, then boot the old hard drive, deactivate that, then start over from step #1 and do the rest.  My thinking is that the original key may be tied to the original hardware config.  Now, since you moved the config, there is some sort of checksum error since the HDD was changed.  I am hoping you can just deactivate and then reactive from the new HW config.  If Windows gives you a hard time, deactivate BOTH the original HDD config and the new SSD config, then only try and activate the SSD config, leaving the HDD config deactivated.

Comment: I ended up getting someone on https://answerdesk.support.microsoft.com to remote control my PC and as I watched, this is basically what they did! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using the OEM Windows copy that came with the notebook...

The activate by phone option won't show up if you're using the generic Windows key that was used by the OEM to install the Windows image at the factory.

You need to [change the key](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows/help/genuine/product-key#T1=tab01) to the one on the COA sticker supplied with the notebook (usually stuck to the bottom), and then restart the activation process.

Then, if online activation doesn't "just work", the phone option should become available.

For more information I recommend you check out this other SU question: [Windows Activation FAQ: How do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit)

Answer (score 0):

I've cloned Windows 7 2 time and Windows 8 once and never had to activate. When you clone you coping the exact state of Windows at the time you clone. The only time Windows needs to be activated is if it's reinstalled. OEM windows allows changing hard drives they are tied to the Mobo and not HD or SSD.