# Dual booting 2 versions of windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot

I would like to put 2 versions of windows 8.1 on my computer, one for games and entertainment stuff and another for programming and research. I am fairly familiar with dual booting other operating systems but I just want to make sure there isn't anything that I should watch out for when dual booting the same OS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 and Vista Activation FAQ: How do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](http://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - I get a totally different read on this question.  Aside from 8.1 vs. 7 and Vista applicability, I didn't see licensing as what was being asked about.

Comment: Generally, other OSes can dual boot with Windows if Windows is already there.  Windows doesn't play well with others in terms of setting up Windows to dual boot with something else, including another Windows.  I don't think this will be an off-the-shelf Windows solution.  You might be looking at something like installing the second Windows on another physical drive while your main drive is disconnected.  Then using function keys at startup to select the boot device.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly cannot think of any issues in dual-booting the same OS so long as you make use of partitions to prevent the OS files from interacting.  You could even conceivably have them share storage folders like your Documents/Pictures/Music/Video library folders if you so choose.