# Can I dual boot Windows 8.1 with the same registration key?

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, serial-number

I would like to optimize my laptop (Dell XPS 9530) for high performance programs (DJ'ing) by having a very clean Windows 8.1 installation with only relevant software and (sound) drivers installed.

Can I install, next to my current cluttered Win 8.1 installation, a new copy of Windows 8.1 using the same OEM registration key (from the bottom of my laptop)? Won't windows complain that the key has already been used?

Thanks in advance!

Related: [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/870935/dual-booting-2-versions-of-windows-8-1) reassures that installation won't give troubles, but doesn't go into the CD key problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should not give you any problems. It may be that it says the key has already been activated once, and you may need to call Microsoft to reactivate the key, but if you just tell them you reinstalled your windows, for example because you got a virus, they will activate it for you.

The idea is that a key is not being activated say... 10 times in a short window, or a large amount of times overall. So one single activation should not matter.

Comment: I have little doubt that technically you are right. Legally however you are installing two copies of the OS. I am pretty sure that two licences are requires.

Comment: Given that you are not using both at the same time, I'm pretty sure no harm is done here, but if you are speaking very strictly, it is indeed not legal. But this question was not regarding if it was legal or not, but if it is possible. Usually the first 2 activations can be done without any problem, and after that you need to activate it using microsoft which is still not a problem. if you are the only user of your product, and in this case, that is the case. One user using his license on the same machine, and thats all that matters.