# free upgrade from win 7 32bit to win7 64 bit if i have original 32 bit licence

Tags: windows-7, windows

hi guys I am running windows 7 original software 32 bit legal licence. I would like to move to windows 7 64 bit. can I do this for free?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 and Vista Activation FAQ: How do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](http://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit)

Comment: Now *that* is a good answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can upgrade from 32-64bit and downgrade to 32bit - you can do that as much as you like.

The only limitation is that you can only do that on the machine the copy is licensed for. This varies depending on the type of version you have. OEM licenses for example are (in theory at least) tied to a single PC. Standard copies can be moved to another PC but only if you remove it from the previous PC first.